# Given that $h - 3\cos(πh) - 32 = 0$. Find h.

Tags: trigonometry

> $h - 3\cos(πh) - 32 = 0$

How do i bring h to one side ? I am really lost on this question and in need of advise!

Comment: This is a transcendental equation. You cannot solve it analytically using elementary functions.

Comment: Checking for odd $h,$ $$h=32-3$$ is a solution. Also, $$-3\le h-32\le3$$

Comment: Do you allow a numerical method rather than an analytical one? If so, use the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: There are $7$ solutions in the interval $[29,35]$, which one do you want to approximate? $x=29$ is a trivial solution.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick response!
@labbhattacharjee i don't understand what you mean by checking for odd h, how do you get the equation h = 32 - 3, i just started calculus this year so i am not very good at it, please be patient with me.

Comment: @user3427783, First of all, for real $h,$  $$-1\le\cos\pi h\le1$ If $h$ is even $\cos(\pi h)=1, h=3+32$ which is odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "formula" that will give you solutions. One can approximate them. But, in this case, when $h $ is an integer we have  $$\cos\pi h=(-1)^h. $$
So, for integer $h $, you equation is $$h=3 (-1)^h+32. $$For $h $ even you have $h=3+32=35, $ so no solution. For $h $ odd, you have $$h=-3+32=29. $$ There are other (non-integer) solutions to the original equation, though.